# Which R package or function to use for meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am interested in combining point-wise survival estimates from Kaplan-Meier curves, e.g. I want to combine the survival estimates at age 70. Which R package/functions should I look into? I see that the `metaprop` function in `meta` combines single proportions. Can I really treat these survival estimates as "proportions"? I guess they are a proportion of # survive past time t/# at risk. Which method of calculating the confidence interval should I use? The default is an exact binomial CI, which I don't think is appropriate.

Or would the `rma.uni` function in the `metafor` pacakge be more appropriate?

Comment: This should be migrated to SO

Comment: See the CRAN Task view or ask on the R meta-analysis mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// Remember to register first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good review of R packages for meta-analyses, found here: http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/1076998616674315

I personally recommend `metafor`—it is the most thoroughly documented, and it is the package of choice from the R meta listserv. Look at the `escalc` function in the `metafor` package for a very detailed account of how to handle your effect sizes and get variance estimates for them.